# Unable to get response from server using json_encode

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am using this code to send response to a request:

```
$data; //some array
```

`$data` has values like

```
array(4) (
  [nextAvail] => (bool) true
  [thisAvail] => (bool) true
  [count] => (int) 15
  [stream] => (string) [html body goes here] 
)
```

I am using:

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

but surprisingly response I received at browser like:

```
{"nextAvail":true,"thisAvail":true,"count":15,"stream":null}
```

I am using jquery post to make request:

```
$.post(ajaxPath, {
        data: data
   }, 
   function(data) {
   }, "json")
```

Please suggest what could possibly go wrong while sending response using json_encode, I tested sending response by removing json_encode and simply using

```
echo print_r($data);
```

it's sending response with no issues.

Comment: Sorry, so what's the problem? Is it that your stream is null but it's not supposed to be?

Comment: Json_encode will create an empty string if the incoming data contains non-UTF8 characters

Comment: did you add the header('Content-Type: application/json'); ?

Answer (score 0):

As I was not expecting character encoding could be a possible problem for me, but indeed it was, using utf8_encode() for encoding html response solved the problem.